# When I disable my microphone device, I can no longer hear Skype

Tags: skype, microphone

When I disable the microphone device, I can no longer hear a conversation in Skype.

I also can't use my microphone.

[image: Device]

I have a microphone and speaker device set in skype.

[image: Audio settings]

Also, sounds on my PC (eg: YouTube videos) are audible to people in my Skype call

When I try to record sounds, instead of recording my microphone input, it records my system audio (ie: voices from the skype call)

[image: record]

I think I'm missing some conceptual understanding of how devices work on windows.

Why does disabling the microphone device cause the above described behavior in Skype?

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear, I want to fix this problem so I can use skype normally again.

Comment: Just add the actual question at the very end. Btw, doesn't Skype let you mute your mic?

Comment: I need my mic unmuted to use skype

Comment: I've tried reinstalling a new version of skype, this did not help

Comment: now that I think about it, I started having this problem after trying to configure speech recognition

Comment: The Realtech High definition audio device can recognize when the microphone is unplugged/plugged in

Comment: @sav I edited your question to hopefully make it more clear what you are after. If you feel my edit changes the intent of your question, by all means do feel free to [edit] further.

Comment: Why do you expect to be able to use a voice communications program with your microphone disabled? Skype needs some kind of input device to work; it's hard-coded into the program that it won't be happy until it has a working input. If you need to give it an input that always outputs silence, just buy Virtual Audio Cable from NTONYX which will provide an input that will only ever produce sound if you are playing to the corresponding output from VAC.

Comment: That's the microphone, not the speakers. Its like the mic and speakers are swapped.

Comment: I finally fixed this when i fixed this other problem here http://superuser.com/questions/683795/how-do-i-swap-back-my-audio-device once I uninstalled realtek, I could set my audio devices and fix my skype audio.