# How do I swap back my audio device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, microphone

It seems my microphone and speaker devices are swapped somehow.

[image: device]

(Note that this device can detect whether my mic is unplugged/ plugged in)

I cannnot input sound using my microphone

However, when I try to record sound

[image: record]

It records system sounds instead of my microphone.

Also, when trying to configure speech recognition

[image: recog]

It picks up system sounds rather than my microphone.

I think I am missing some conceptual understanding of how devices work on windows.

How do I fix this so I can use my microphone again?

**EDIT**

[image: realtec]

[image: mic]

I'm currently using the pink front panel for mic input

Comment: On your front panel the have the pink and green, try either swapping them in the audio manager or plugging the speakers into pink instead and the mic into green instead.

Comment: I've tried swapping these in all combinations. Still no luck. I've also tried dual booting my PC with linux and using skype on ubuntu. My mic works on Ubuntu fine, so its not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out

I uninstalled realtek, unfortunately it seems I had to do this.

then set my speaker and mic to default device as in pics below

[image: mic]

[image: speaker]

Answer (score 1):

As you're using Realtek you could try opening the Realtek audio manager swapping what port does what by right clicking on the port on the right hand side and chose connector retasking.

It's worked for me before when i needed to swap something - so hopefully fixes your issue.